# Merge with Map-Reduce. Multiple keys in one dataset

Tags: hadoop, merge, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I have two datasets:

```
Dataset1:

Emp1 Emp2 Salary



Dataset2

Emp add1 add2 add3
```

The data in the Dataset 2 consists of all the employees which exist in Emp1 or Emp2 in the dataset1.

The resultant dataset needs have each row of Dataset1 and add1 add2 add3 variables of both the employess emp1 and emp2.

```
Dataset3

Emp1 Emp2 add1(emp1) add2(emp1)  add3(emp1) add1(emp2) add2(emp2)  add3(emp2)
```

It is basically a merge over 2 datasets but when i try and get keys from first dataset, I can get Emp1 Emp2 in a column and can get Emp1 Emp3 in another column. How do I accomplish this using map reduce since the keys are getting confused?

Comment: Can you do two round MapReduce? In the first round, just handle the emp1. In the second round, complete the emp2.

Comment: I do not know if I understood correctly, but basically, you have Dataset1, which contains a list of employees and their salary; a Dataset2 which contains some increments for all employees? And what you are trying to achieve is to obtain the "final salary of each employee"?

Comment: Can you add more lines in your dataset1, dataset2, and dataset3 and tell us how Hadoop is getting confused with keys?

Comment: I'm confused what "confused" means in the context of MR keys!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to realise a *"Merge MR Job"*, you have to take care that the data records, which shall be merged, arrive at the same `Reducer`. Therefore your `Mappers` have to emit these single records (aka Key-Value-Pairs) with an appropriate `Key`. I'd recommend to **[implement your own key class](http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module5.html#keytypes).**

Your key could be named "TwoEmployees" or "EmployeePair" or so. In every case to work as an MR key it has to **implement [WritableComparable](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/WritableComparable.html)**. Then it should have two fields `emp1` and `emp2`.

The Mappers of Dataset1 will emit key-value-pairs where the key contains both employees and the value contains the salary.

The Mappers of Dataset2 will emit key-value-pairs where only emp1 is set in the key and the value is a complex object carrying all the address information.

Now the magic to make these different key-value-pairs go to the same reducer is to **implement the `compareTo()`-method** in the `key` class in a way that ("A. Anderson", "B. Bakeman") equals ("B. Bakeman", null) and also equals ("A. Anderson", null).

Now your reducer will receive one record from dataset1 and two from dataset2. It can emit the merged record as final key-value-pair.